# Getting a form to choose between dropdown or textbox for one field

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

The situation: I've got this `form` needs to read in a few pieces of information from my page/view to store it for use in the controller that is accessed after hitting a button on the `form`.  The problem is that I've got both a `dropdownlist` and a `textbox` that I'm trying to use to represent one property on the `form`.  Does anybody know how I can effectively get the `form` to choose the correct control to read in from for that property?

The form's model:

```
    public class EventListForm
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public virtual string Location { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public virtual string AccessPoints { get; set; }
    }
```

The View the form is on including the controls that it will read from:

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Event", new { }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "selectEditEventForm" }))   { %>
    <table class="data-table">
      <tr>
        <td><label for="Id" class="xl">Event:</label></td>
        <td><%=Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Id, Model.Events.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.AsDecimal()), new { @class = "info1" })%></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="Location" class="xl">Location:</label></td>
        <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Location, new { @class = "location info2 xl", maxlength = "250" })%></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><label for ="AccessPoint" class="xl">Access Point:</label></td>
         <td><%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Id, Model.AccessPoints.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.AsDecimal()), new { @id = "selectAccessPoint", @class = "info2"})%></td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
         <td><label for ="AccessPoint" class="xl" >Or Add New:</label></td>
         <td><%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AccessPoints, new { @id = "newAccessPoint", @class = "location info2", maxlength = "250" }) %></td>
      </tr>
```

I have included JS to disable the `textbox` if the `dropdownlist` is used and to disable the `dropdownlist` if the `textbox` is used.  Obviously I can get the `form` to read from the `textbox` if the `dropdownlist` isn't on the page but I can't get the `form` to read from the `dropdownlist` if the `textbox` isn't on the page.  Can point me in the right direction?  should I just include another property on the `form`?

Comment: Are you just looking for a string value to be returned on submit or do you need the index?

Comment: I'm just looking for the string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you do not need the index, I would go down the route of adding a hidden input ad copying the value from either the dropdown or the textbox on submit.
Not sure how this fits your usage though.

Comment: Could you perhaps give me an example of this?  I only need the value to push it to my database from the controller.

Comment: I have an idea of how to do that, create a hidden `textbox` and have the `dropdownlist` and the input `textbox` just copy their values into it on submit but how would I actually go about writing the code for that?  I'm not sure what the HTML for that would be, would I need a `HTML.HiddenFor(` but then it would have to reference the model and the model doesn't have another property for that...

Comment: Alternatively it may be simpler to just copy the text from the drop-down to the text-box and use the text-box value regardless of which is visible.